# WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!

Tags: aws, ssh, ec2

Ayuda. Solia trabajar con `AWS` incluso convirtiendo a `ppk` via `putty` pero las nuevas instacias que creo recientemente tienen este problema, no se como arreglarlo.

he visto muchas soluciones cambiando permisos pero es en `linux` y yo estoy en `windows`, tambien lo probé en `linux`, pero nada, he retirado permisos y nada.

llevo varios dias con este problema. ya le cambié permisos y un monton de tonterias pero nada, ya me llegó al #### la seguridad y todo, hay una forma de saltarse?

```
PS D:\meyam\Desktop> ssh -i "ubuntu.pem" ubuntu@ec2-34-219-19-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-34-219-19-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (34.219.19.145)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:DE+7RYmMK+lnA4aqigH4Zk2W+BnZFCaQ+zkxjrfMGDk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-219-19-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com,34.219.19.145' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'ubuntu.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "ubuntu.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@ec2-34-219-19-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas bien, la clave es accesible por **todos** los usuarios que pertenezcan al grupo *Usuarios*.

Tienes que eliminar ese permiso y añadir únicamente tu usuario.

Piensa que SSH no sabe si en tu equipo hay un único usuario registrado o 300, y aunque lo supiese y viese que efectivamente, en el grupo *Usuarios* solo estás tu, eso no garantiza que en el futuro no se añada un segundo usuario, el cual tendría acceso a tu clave privada.